# Using shared library with Conan.io within Android

Tags: android, conan

I have a pre-built shared library (architecture ARM) which I exported as a conan package:

```
conan export-pkg .. ext/stable --force -pr android_19_arm_clang
```

Next I want to use this library in my Android project. I have Conan and CMake setup like this.

**conanfile.txt:**

```
[requires]
LibraryName/0.1@ext/stable
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
...
conan_basic_setup(NO_OUTPUT_DIRS)
...
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                  myOwnAndroidLib-lib
                  android
                  ${CONAN_LIBS}
                  )
...
```

Since the the pre-built library is a ".so" library I have to put it into the jniLibs Folder of my Android project. This part is missing in the conan/Android docs. How can I instrument conan to place the *.so files in the jniLibs folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy pre-built packages to a specific folder when building, you should use the feature `imports`:

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/conanfile_txt.html#imports

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile_txt.html#imports